# Find sum of 5 positive integers (one input) without looping

Tags: java, sum

how do i do this where it prompts for only one number? not 5 inputs of 
   separate numbers? I can't loop (we're only on chapter 2 for school), even though I know it's more logical to use:

**the assignment was to only use % or / to find the sum of the 5 digit integer**

```
 /*  while( Number > 0) {
    Remainder = Number % 10;
    Sum = Sum + Remainder;
    Number = Number / 10;
    System.out.format("sum: "+ Sum);
  */
```

also can someone explain in layman's terms, the modulus and / getting the  sum. thank you!

---

```
//Scanner is in the java.util package
import java.util.Scanner; //import class

public class SumOf5Digits {

private static Scanner input;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a 5-digit positive integer: ");
    int Number1, Remainder1;
    int Number2, Remainder2;
    int Number3, Remainder3;
    int Number4, Remainder4;
    int Number5, Remainder5;
    int Sum = 0;

    Number1 = input.nextInt();
    Number2 = input.nextInt();
    Number3 = input.nextInt();
    Number4 = input.nextInt();
    Number5 = input.nextInt();

    Remainder1 = Number1 % 10;
    Number1 = Number1 /10;
    Remainder2 = Number2 % 10;
    Number2 = Number2 /10;
    Remainder3 = Number3 % 10;
    Number3 = Number3 /10;
    Remainder4 = Number4 % 10;
    Number4 = Number4 /10;
    Remainder5 = Number5 % 10;
    Number5 = Number5 /10;

    Sum = Sum + (Remainder1 + Remainder2 + Remainder3 + Remainder4 + 
    Remainder5);

    System.out.format ("sum:" + Sum);

}
```

Comment: I think the idea is to read in *one* 5 digit integer and then sum the digits. You're reading in 5 integers.

Comment: Q: Is this homework?  Q: What does modulus (or remainder) have to do with "finding the sum of five numbers"?  GUESS: Maybe you're supposed to read *ONE* integer ... and then sum each of the base-10 digits (up to five) of that integer?

Comment: yes it's homework. already submitted it! bothering me. we have to find the sum only using modulus and /

Comment: @paulsm4 yes i think you're right. One integer, i just don't know how to write sum each of the base-10 up to five times lmao #noob

Comment: The modulus + division extracts the digit. The modulus gives you the numeric value of the rightmost digit and the division "shifts" the digits right by one. Although I don't understand why you're not supposed to use loops, but still. You've got basically the correct code, except you've just used 5 times too many variables and inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
import java.util.Scanner; //import class

public class SumOf5Digits {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

     // Read integer
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Enter a 5-digit positive integer: ");
     int number = input.nextInt();

     // Compute sum of up to five base-10 digits in the number
     int sum = 0;
     if (number > 99999) {
        System.out.println("WARNING: " + number + " has more than five base-10 digits");
     } else {
       int digit = number % 10;  System.out.println("digit[0]=" + digit);
       sum += digit;
       digit = (number/10) % 10;  System.out.println("digit[1]=" + digit);
       sum += digit;
       digit = (number/100) % 10;  System.out.println("digit[2]=" + digit);
       sum += digit;
       digit = (number/1000) % 10;  System.out.println("digit[3]=" + digit);
       sum += digit;
       digit = (number/10000) % 10;  System.out.println("digit[4]=" + digit);
       sum += digit;
     }

     // Print sum
     System.out.println("Sum=" + sum);
  }
}
```

Example output:

```
Enter a 5-digit positive integer: 22222
digit[0]=2
digit[1]=2
digit[2]=2
digit[3]=2
digit[4]=2
Sum=10
```